# enter an if statement if multiple conditions are true in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to enter an if/then statement only if these conditions are true:

```
if [ "$key1dtSec" -lt "$taSec" ] || [ "$key2dtSec" -lt "$taSec" ] && [[ ! -z "$user_lives_here" ]]; then
```

I want to enter the loop only if `$key1dtSec` OR `$key2dtsec` are true AND only if `$user_lives_here` has a value.

But the `if`/`then` statement gets executed even if `$user_lives_here` has a value. And I don't want that.

How can I ensure the `if`/`then` only happens if `$user_lives_here` has a value?

Answer (score 3):

You can group your conditions with parenthesis inside the `[[` / `]]` operators:

```
if [[ ! -z "$user_lives_here" && ( "$key1dtSec" -lt "$taSec" || "$key2dtSec" -lt "$taSec" ) ]]
```

Comment: The answer is good, but it is unnecessarily cluttered.  Try: `if [[ $user_lives_here && (key1dtSec -lt taSec || key2dtSec -lt taSec) ]]`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your OR `||` condition in parentheses:

```
if  ( [ "$key1dtSec" -lt "$taSec" ] || [ "$key2dtSec" -lt "$taSec" ] ) && [[ ! -z "$user_lives_here" ]]; then
```

Comment: Using `{...}` would be more efficient, to avoid unnecessary subshells.